# A cheap way to frequently check connection to MS SQL Server from client app?

Tags: sql-server, client-server, ping

In relatively small server-client environment (up to 100 client connections to database server) what is the resource-effective way for every running client application to check whether its database connection is alive?

I was thinking about implementing execution of `SELECT 1` every 20 seconds from every client app.

Is this good enough or is there something more clever?

Many users can be working with the database via mobile connection which can have frequent dropouts so my idea was to **indicate such a dropout in the client application and warn before user submits the form etc.**
I know ideal for users would be running app client remotely through Citrix or MS Terminal Services solution, but very often they have only simple VPN, nothing more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More effective than `SELECT 1`  or  `PRINT ''` can be sending of

`a:`

what is a label declaration. Or

`--`

what is a comment.
It sends back no output except of basic 'Success' code
(interpreted as `'Command(s) completed successfully.'`).

**EDIT:** as seen in comments below, a single space () is sufficient. The commenter did not post the reply until now so I'm modifying mine.

Comment: That's funny. Consider sending a single space.

Comment: And fancy version of the same is `_:` which I just found to be working well :)

Comment: @usr – Single space works great. I totally forgot about this simplification. Please post the answer and if no one gives even better one, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK there isn't a SQL Server ping function, I've relied on SELECT statements in the past.
I've used SELECT @@SERVERNAME, which returns just a single row and is also pretty efficient.

Or having a dedicated table with just item in it and selecting that.

The SqlConnection.State property isn't reliable as that indicates state after the last operation, so if the server has gone down since then it'll give you the incorrect state.